# Vuetify v-data-table with vuex. Not rendering in unit test

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

vue 2.5.2
vuex 3.0.1
vuetify 1.0.16

I'm creating vuex+vuetify application.

Rendering data is in the vuex store.
It uses v-data-table with pagination.

The component code is

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-text-field id="shopName" v-model="editedItem.name" required></v-text-field>
    <v-btn id="save" color="blue darken-1" flat @click.native="save">save</v-btn>
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :pagination.sync="pagination" :items="shops" class="elevation-1">
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      </template>
      <template slot="no-data">
          <td>no item</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'shop',
  created () {
  },
  data () {
    return {
      pagination: {
        sortBy: 'name'
      },
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'name',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'name'
        }
      ],
      editedItem: {name: ''},
      defaultItem: {name: ''}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    close () {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
      }, 300)
    },
    save () {
      this.$store.commit('addShop', this.editedItem)
      this.close()
    }
  },
  computed: {
    shops () {
      return this.$store.state.items
    }
  },
  mounted () {
  }
}
</script>
```

And I added test code.
First one is 'adds a new shop' test , that add store.
The test passed.

And next test 'uses same store' is rendering with same store instance.
But test not passed.
When removing pagination setting from component, then test passed.
Why not rendering when pagination setting existing.

```
import { mount } from 'avoriaz'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import DataTable from '@/components/DataTable'
import { store } from '../../../src/store/store.js'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

describe('Shop.vue', () => {
  it('adds a new shop', async () => {
    // build component
    const wrapper = mount(DataTable, {store})
    const inputShopName = wrapper.find('input#shopName')[0]
    inputShopName.trigger('focus')
    inputShopName.element.value = 'AEON'
    inputShopName.trigger('input')
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    wrapper.find('button#save')[0].trigger('click')
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('AEON')
  })
  it('uses same store', () => {
    // build component
    const wrapper2 = mount(DataTable, {store})
    expect(wrapper2.html()).toContain('AEON')
  })
})
```

Reproduction code in
https://github.com/dokechin/vue-test-example

Comment: 'uses same store' test rendered contents in pagination.  <div class=\"datatable__actions__pagination\">NaN-NaN of 1</div>

Comment: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/632  and https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmbwZa           I solved my problem with my self.

Comment: Oh not solved yet, I mistyped code sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I tried changed my problem more simple.
Making store data before mounting, not rendering when pagination.sync exists.

```
import { mount } from 'avoriaz'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import DataTable from '@/components/DataTable'
import { store } from '../../../src/store/store.js'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

describe('Shop.vue', () => {
  it('uses store', () => {
    // build component
    store.state.items.push({name: 'AEON'})
    const wrapper2 = mount(DataTable, {store})
    expect(wrapper2.html()).toContain('AEON')
  })
})
```

Comment: I'will wait for the release of pull 3857.